# Blurring images of an image pyramid - Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector

I am trying to load an image, calculate the image pyramid (save every image) and then blur every single image of the pyramid with opencv 3.2 in C++. When I run my program I receive the error:

> vector Line:1740 Expression: vector subscript out of range

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/shape/shape.hpp> 

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    // Read the image
    Mat img_1;
    img_1 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    // Build an image pyramid and save it in a vector of Mat
    vector<Mat> img_1_pyramid;
    int pyramid_octaves = 3;
    buildPyramid(img_1, img_1_pyramid, pyramid_octaves); 
    /* void cv::buildPyramid (InputArray src, OutputArrayOfArrays dst, int 
    maxlevel, int borderType = BORDER_DEFAULT) */   

    // Initialize parameters for the first image pyramid
    vector<Mat> reduced_noise_1;
    blur(img_1_pyramid[0], reduced_noise_1[0], Size(3,3));
    /* void cv::blur (InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size ksize, Point 
    anchor=Point(-1,-1), int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT)*/

return 0;
}
```

I also tried it with a Mat object: `Mat reduced_noise_1;` or a vector of predefined size `vector<Mat> reduced_noise(4);`and I can draw `img_1_pyramid[0]` with `imshow` and receive the right image...

When I debug the program I receive an error in Line 621 of cvstd.hpp:

```
String::String(const char* s)
    : cstr_(0), len_(0)
{
    if (!s) return;
    size_t len = strlen(s);  // Here appears the error (only in German;))
    memcpy(allocate(len), s, len);
}
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]. For example, the declaration of `buildPyramid`. It might not be receiving the vector by reference.

Comment: I don't know much about opencv, but when you call `blur`, `reduced_noise_1[0]` is out of range because that vector is empty. Since you're effectively passing a non-existent object and not the vector itself the function can't do anything to change that vector's size.

Comment: I tried to correct it.